# LoadEnclaveImage "A device attached to the system is not functioning"

Tags: c++, enclave

I'm trying to load a signed DLL into a VBS enclave and `LoadEnclaveImage` is returning `A device attached to the system is not functioning`.

Hyper-V, Secure Boot, & TPM 2.0 are all functioning, so I'm not quite sure as to what the error is referring to.

Sample Code:

```
if (IsEnclaveTypeSupported(ENCLAVE_TYPE_VBS))
{
    DWORD lpError = 0;
    ENCLAVE_CREATE_INFO_VBS vci = { 0 };
    vci.Flags = 1;

    PVOID enclave = CreateEnclave(GetCurrentProcess(),
        NULL,
        1024 * 1024 * 2,
        NULL,
        ENCLAVE_TYPE_VBS,
        &vci,
        sizeof(ENCLAVE_CREATE_INFO_VBS),
        &lpError);

    if (enclave != NULL)
    {
        auto lib = LoadLibrary(L"kernelbase.dll");
        auto addr = (__LoadEnclaveImage)GetProcAddress(lib, "LoadEnclaveImageW");

        if (addr(enclave, L"...\testme.dll"))
        {
            printf("Worked!\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Failed to load image\n");
            printf(GetLastErrorAsString().c_str());
        }

    }
    else
    {
        printf(GetLastErrorAsString().c_str());
    }
}
else {
    printf("VBS not supported\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same general error when loading a signed DLL, so I looked for usages of `LoadEnclaveImageW` in other system binaries using [Static Import Finder](http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/staticimportfinder/), and found it in SgrmBroker.exe where it loads "SgrmEnclave_secure.dll". Attempting to use `LoadEnclaveImageW` with that DLL was successful.

Digging deeper into the PE structure of the "SgrmEnclave_secure.dll" file, we can see that a value is defined for `EnclaveConfigurationPointer` in the [`IMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY64` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_load_config_directory64) (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdiQW.png) from PE-bear).

This pointer points to an [`IMAGE_ENCLAVE_CONFIG64` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_enclave_config64) and this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAFpH.png) shows what it looks like when parsed in Ghidra. The `ImportList` member is an RVA for a series of [`IMAGE_ENCLAVE_IMPORT` structures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_enclave_import).

So it looks like these structures need to be defined in the PE. This can be done using the `/ENCLAVE` option in the linker. Not sure if there are additional requirements. Should you get further with this, I'd be interested to know.